# NGINX X-Frame-Options allow only from single page

Tags: linux, webserver, website, nginx, iframe

I am trying to setup my vHost to allow iframes from only one subdomain of our network. Before we had:

`add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";` on all our pages.

To accomplish what I want to do I tried:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options https://somewebsite.com;
```

This ends up allowing iframes as wanted but it allows them from every domain not just from `https://somewebsite.com`.

How can I deny iframes from all external pages but allow them from one subdomain?

**Side info:**

both sites run on the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

The [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034) for the `X-Frame-Options` header states that valid options for the header are:

- `DENY`
- `SAMEORIGIN`
- `ALLOW-FROM <uri>`

So, first off you need to add `ALLOW-FROM` then specify the URI of your subdomain.  Something like this:

```
ALLOW-FROM https://subdomain.example.com/
```

Comment: I added `add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://sub.example.com";` to my vHost configuration file. This ends in the same behaviour as before --> iframing is allowed from any domain. Does the used Browser have an effect on this. I am using Google Chrome (48.0.2564.103)

Comment: See the table at the bottom of [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).  Apparently Chrome does not support `ALLOW-FROM`.

Comment: How can I enable multiple URI only?